# How to map generic list into another generic list?

Tags: java, arraylist, mapping

Lets say i have two generic lists.
I want to map one generic values from list into another.

So List  <.NameAndSurnameDto> needs to be mapped into another List <.NameAndSurnameDtoTwo>.

What is the best way to do such operation?

Comment: Can you add more informations ? What is the relation between NameAndSurnameDto and NameAndSurnameDtoTwo ? Inheritance ? Just two classes ?  Please put some code you have try and that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
List <NameAndSurnameDto> list1; //assuming this is called list1

List <NameAndSurnameDtoTwo> list2 = list1.stream().map(nameAndSurnameDto -> {
         return new NameAndSurnameDtoTwo( 
               ... map properties of nameAndSurnameDto to NameAndSurnameDtoTwo      
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This would work, but is it really better than a for loop?  Especially for a beginner?